# $out stage of mongo aggregation pipeline not taking effect using node

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, node-mongodb-native

Long time listener, first time caller here.

I'm using node drivers to execute an aggregate command on mongo and the `$out` stage seems to only take effect if certain methods are chained.

I want to call `aggregate()` with $out as the last stage of the pipeline and then callback. Currently, it only works if I chain `next()` or `toArray()` which is irksome since the [method signature](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate) is aggregate(pipeline, options, **callback**).

Examples below simplified for clarity.

Here, I use the callback and $out does NOT take effect (i.e. newNames isn't created but the callback is executed). I'm refactoring stuff from a few months back and this was working previously (version 2.2.33 of the node driver):

```
db.collection('names')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: {} }, 
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $out: 'newNames' }
  ], (err, result) => {
    // result is an AggregationCursor
    callback();
  });
```

If I don't add a callback but chain next() instead, the $out stage DOES take effect

```
db.collection('names')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $out: 'newNames' }
  ])
  .next((err, result) => {
    // result is null, why?
    callback();
  });
```

It also DOES work if you chain toArray:

```
db.collection('names')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: {} }, 
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $out: 'newNames' }
  ])
  .toArray((err, result) => {
    // result is an empty array (i.e. the resulting docs), OK, makes sense
    callback();
  });
```

So I thought I must be misunderstanding Promises vs callbacks, but it does NOT take effect if I use close() either which is chained and the result is back to being an AggregationCursor:

```
db.collection('names')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $out: 'newNames' }
  ])
  .close((err, result) => {
    // result is an AggregationCursor
    callback();
  });
```

Reading through some of the [responses](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/9d12ac3cc64fed4bff75f7cc9667ab2f5c2cf305) to issues, it seems the AggregationCursor vs Resulting Documents is expected. But I don't get why $out isn't taking effect when I go to the callback or chain close().

- mongo 3.6.2 inside the mongo:latest docker image
- Docker 17.12.0
- node 8.9.0

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this myself too.  I called cursor.next() until a null was received and the $out aggregation worked.  Using async / await makes this easy.  Without these this could get pretty messy looking.

```
var cursor = await db.collection('names')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    { $limit: 1 },
    { $out: 'newNames' }
  ]);

var next = null;
do {
   next = await cursor.next();
} while (next != null);
```